# Python Request returning 200 status code but not doing what I want

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm quite new to Python, but I'm trying to make my own sneakers bot for a European website called Zalando.

I'm using requests to automate the process of adding an item to my cart, but it's not working how I want it to. When I print the status code, it returns 200 but doesn't add the item to my cart which is what I'm trying to achieve.

Partial Code:

```
session = requests.Session()

def create_atc_payload():

    payload =   {
            '0': {"id":"e7f9dfd05f6b992d05ec8d79803ce6a6bcfb0a10972d4d9731c6b94f6ec75033","variables":{"addToCartInput":{"productId":"NI115O002-Q120115000","clientMutationId":"addToCartMutation"}}}
    }

    return payload


def login():
    global session

    with open('zalando.csv', mode = 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        line_count = 0
        firstline = True
        for row in csv_reader:
            if firstline:
                firstline = False
                continue

            headers = {
                'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36' ,
                'Cookie' : 'cookie'
                }
            
            endpoint = "https://www.zalando.ie/cart"

            p = session.post(endpoint, data=create_atc_payload(), headers=headers, timeout = 10)
            print(p.status_code)
            time.sleep(4)
            
            response = session.get(endpoint, headers=headers)

            soup = bs(response.text, "html.parser")

            classes = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"z-coast-base__article-in-cart"})

            cart = []

            for item in classes:
                item_id = item["id"]
                cart.append(item_id)

            line_count += 1
        
    print(cart)

login()
```

Output:

```
200
[]
```

When I add the item to my cart manually and then use the 'get' request, It correctly prints it out like this:

```
200
['article-NI115O002-Q120115000']
```

My friend has written a chrome extension script using JavaScript and uses the same method, and his works. I've spent the last 3 days trying to find a solution and have been losing sleep over it. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried passing the data (payload) in as json instead? You would either do `json=payload `on your request or `data=json.dumps(payload)`

Comment: I just tried both of your suggestions but neither of them seemed to fix the issue

Comment: Hi, any solution for your problem? I'm trying to do the same thing..